# typeof construction method

Tags: javascript, typeof

Hi guys I need to write a if state that validates the if the input isa  number and makes sure that number is between two numbers.  What I came up with so far is this:

```
typeof($("#frequencyInput")=== 'number')
typeof($("#frequencyInput")=== 'number' >= 1 <= 59)
```

The first line I'm validating it as a number but I'm hoping I can use the second one alone to validate the information being entered is a number and between 1 and less than 59.  Also for the "Text Input" box I set a maxLength=2.

Comment: The second line is not valid, please read up on conditional operators

Comment: A jQuery selector on its own will return a typeof object. You need to pull the value from your selected element and test that value.

Comment: Both lines make no sense. The first will always return `"boolean"` and the second is a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

A few things based on your code provided.

1: A jQuery selector will return a typeof Object. Assuming it is an input you would need to use `.val()` to get the value of the selected input.

2: `typeof $('#frequencyInput').val()` is going to return a typeof string.

You would need to `parseInt()` to convert the string to an integer which would give you a typeof number.

`var input = parseInt($('#frequencyInput').val());`

Then validate with your if statement:

`if ( typeof input === 'number' && input >= 1 && input <= 59 ) { .. }`

However! If you try to `parseInt()` on a non-numeric number it will return `NaN` for Not a Number. You could use a regex pattern to limit the input or parse out anything that isn't a number from your input to avoid this.

Comment: Wild Beard you are awesome!  Thanks  exactly what I needed

Comment: @GabePerry glad I could help! Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem!